# How to find limit of function: $\lim_{x\to 0}\left(x{{\left\lfloor{ \frac{1}{x}} \right\rfloor}}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Find $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\left(x{{\left\lfloor{ \frac{1}{x}} \right\rfloor}}\right)$.

When $x\to0^{+}$ I have  $\left(x{\left\lfloor{ \frac{1}{x}} \right\rfloor}\right)\to 0\cdot \infty$.

When $\to 0^{-}$ I have  $\left(x{\left\lfloor{ \frac{1}{x}} \right\rfloor}\right)\to 0\cdot \infty$.

I have no idea,

Comment: near $0^{+}$ it is $+\infty$

Comment: near $0^{-1}$ $- \infty$

Comment: Duplicate: [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\left(x{{\left\lfloor{ \frac{1}{x}} \right\rfloor}}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/879530/201168). (*Found using [Approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%200%7D(x%7B%7B%5Clfloor%7B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D%7D%20%5Crfloor%7D%7D)%24&p=1)*)

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letting $x\to0+$ is the same as letting ${1\over x}=:y\to\infty$, i.e.,
$$\lim_{x\to0+}\bigl(x\>\lfloor 1/x\rfloor\bigr)=\lim_{y\to\infty}{\lfloor y\rfloor\over y}\ .$$
Since $\ y-1<\lfloor y\rfloor\leq y$ it follows that the limit is $1$, by the squeeze theorem. The case $x\to0-$ leads to $y\to-\infty$, and is similar.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**:
For $x\gt0$,
$$
1-x=x\left(\frac1x-1\right)\le x\left\lfloor\frac1x\right\rfloor\le x\left(\frac1x\right)=1
$$
The inequalities are reversed for $x\lt0$, but you can still apply the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) in both cases.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: Use the definition of the floor function. If $\frac1{n+1}<x\le\frac1n$ for some positive integer $n$, then $n\le\frac1x<n+1$, so $\left\lfloor\frac1x\right\rfloor=n$, and

$$\frac{n}{n+1}<x\left\lfloor\frac1x\right\rfloor<\frac{n+1}n\;;$$

what are the limits of $\frac{n}{n+1}$ and $\frac{n+1}n$ as $n\to\infty$?

Now do something similar for $x<0$.